# Websocket connection failed on macOS with Docker Desktop (works on Linux)

Tags: docker, macos, websocket

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  container-php:
    build:
      context: ./container-php
    volumes:
      - ${path}:/var/www/project
    image: container-php
    container_name: container_php
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.129.3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
networks:
  net:
    ipam:
      config:
        -   subnet: 192.168.129.0/24
```

The WebSocket server is started from within the container-php container and is accessible at the address 192.168.129.3:8080.

When attempting to connect using Postman with the address ws://192.168.129.3:8080/ , it fails to establish a connection after approximately 20 seconds of waiting. However, if I send a message to the WebSocket address from within the same container, it works perfectly and I receive every message as expected.

The issue appears to be related to accessing the WebSocket from outside of the container. I need this to be accessed through the browser or Postman from my local computer.

This Docker Compose configuration functions correctly on a Linux machine. I can even ping 192.168.129.3 from my local terminal. However, on macOS, the ping command does not work.

How do I expose this IP to my local macOS environment?

I use latest Docker Desktop version for macOS.

EDIT: I set the ports to 8080:8080 and now I can connect to the WS through ws://0.0.0.0:8080. Any idea how to make it work through 192.168.129.3?

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are unusable on Docker Desktop or any other VM-based Docker setup, and even on a native Linux system it's not usually a best practice to directly use them.  Can you publish `ports:` from your container and connect to it that way?

Comment: I updated the .yml config. Ports added as like 8080:8080 if I understand correctly. Doesn't make any difference. Or I should define them in some other way? @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker-internal IP addresses are unusable, except for on one very specific setup (a native Linux host directly running the Docker engine without Docker Desktop or another VM-based setup).  You can't connect to them, you never need to look them up, and you almost never need to set them.

The correct way to connect to a container from the host is to publish `ports:`.  The second `ports:` number needs to match what the process in the container is using.  From outside a container but on the same system as the container, connect to `localhost` and the first `ports:` number.  In your example you've published port 8080, so you'd connect to `ws://localhost:8080` or `ws://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Connections between containers can use a Docker-provided DNS system to find other container information.  In between that ability and the container-private IP addresses being unreachable, you never need to know or set them.  I'd also suggest just deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the file, both at the top level and in the container definition.

---

Docker Desktop runs a hidden Linux VM.  If you've succeeded in using the container-private IP address on a native-Linux host, this only works from the same system where Docker is running, and in Docker Desktop that "same system" constraint means "only from inside the Linux VM".  Desktop doesn't set up any IP forwarding or routing that would make the internal IP addresses accessible from anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you, yes 127.0.0.1:8080 with ports set accordingly works fine.